Freezing first two columns while horizontal scrolling using XPTABLE library
I am using window application with c# as technology. Currently I am using XPTable library for showing the records but I am unable to freeze the first two columns while performing horizontal scrolling. Please suggest a way how to do with using XPTable library.
I am using the panel container inside it place the XPModel table and perform the scroll event of panel, but no luck.
Please suggest.
